# Tourist on alien planet. Has human guide. Worries intelligent aliens will eat him..Shocked guide explains they would never eat a human during the day

Tags: story-identification, aliens, planets

I am not 100% sure it is a short story. It might be part of a novel.

The man being given the tour explains to his human guide that he is worried the aliens might eat them.

The guide is shocked at the idea the aliens would eat anyone during daylight. He uses a term to describe such an act as absolutely forbidden. The guide completely trusts the aliens to obey their own rules.
The tourist wonders what is to stop the aliens capturing and tying them up now, then eating them after nightfall.
I read it in the 80s.

I may have remembered more. Maybe it was a woman in the tour group who worried they might get eaten. A younger man in the group who wondered why the aliens could not capture them now and eat them after sunset.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think that it might be a scene in Robert A. Heinlein's *Starman Jones* (1953).

The protagonist is a teenage crew member on an interstellar space liner.  He takes part in a tour on a planet they visit.  One of the aliens looks at a plump middle age female passenger and says something to the guide, and the guide tells the woman that the alien commented that she would probably taste delicious.  The guide says she doesn't have to worry since the natives never eat humans during the daylight.

And it is quite possible that Jones wondered why didn't the aliens capture them in daytime to eat during the night.

> Their driver, Herr Eisenberg, interpreted for them. The native who sold the souvenirs kept swiveling his eyes, one after another, at Mrs. Mendoza. He twittered some remarks to the driver, who guffawed. “What does he say?” she asked.
>
> “He was complementing you.”
>
> “So? But how?”
>
> “Well…he says you are for a slow fire and no need for seasoning; you’d cook up nicely. And he’d do it, too,” the colonist added, “if you stayed here after dark.”
>
> Mrs. Mendoza gave a little scream. “You didn’t tell us they were cannibals. Josie, take me back!”
>
> Herr Eisenberg looked horrified. “Cannibals? Oh, no, lady! They don’t eat each other, they just eat us—when they can get us, that is. But there hasn’t been an incident in twenty years.”
>
> “But that’s worse!”
>
> “No, it isn’t, lady. Look at it from their viewpoint. They’re civilized. This old fellow would never break one of their laws. But to them we are just so much prime beef, unfortunately hard to catch.”
>
> “Take us back at once! Why, there are hundreds of them, and only five of us.”
> .
> “Thousands, lady. But you are safe as long as Gneeri is shining.” He gestured at Nu Pegasi. “It’s bad juju to kill meat during daylight. The spirit stays around to haunt.”
>
> Despite his reassurances the party started back. Max noticed that Eldreth had been unfrightened. He himself had wondered what had kept the natives from tying them up until dark

The guide said that eating humans wouldn't be cannibalism because humans are members of a different species.  And the definition of cannibalism is eating members of the same species.  And that passage made me think that there should  be a word for eating a member of an intelligent species and that doing so should be considered as horrible as cannibalism.

There are a number of highly intelligent species on Earth whose intelligence ranges might greatly overlap a lot with that of humans.  So I think that killing members of those species should be considered to me murder and eating members of those species should be considered to be as bad as cannibalism.

And such attitudes would be good practice in case aliens ever visit Earth.  If someone tried eating an alien visitor, the other aliens might not be as forgiving as the Earthmen in *Starman Jones* - or as forgiving as Darth Vader, for that matter.

Comment: Yes this is it. Thank you.

Comment: "Well . . . he says you are for a slow fire and no need for seasoning; you'd cook up nicely. And he'd do it, too," the colonist added, "if you stayed here after dark."       Mrs. Mendoza gave a little scream. "You didn't tell us they were _cannibals_.

Comment: Then later..no, lady! They don't eat each other, they just eat us-- when they can get us, that is. But there hasn't been an incident in twenty years."       "But that's worse!"       "No, it isn't, lady. Look at it from their viewpoint. They're civilized. This old fellow would never break one of their laws. But to them we are just so much prime beef, unfortunately hard to catch."       "Take us back at once! Why, there are hundreds of them, and only five of us."       "Thousands, lady. But you are safe as long as Gneeri is shining." H "It's bad juju to kill meat during daylight.

Comment: Max......He himself had wondered what had kept the natives from tying them up until dark.

Comment: I'm sad that I did not recognize this. I need to reread the book.

Comment: Quote added! Feel free to revert it if you don't like it.

Comment: It's great. Thank you. How do I add a quote with the vertical line like that?

Comment: @JudithJones you can put a ">" before the quote, or highlight it and use the "double quote" icon above the edit box.